# node_redis callback arguments

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Super basic question- how do I know what format I should give my callback for various node_redis calls?

Seems like some examples out there have two arguments (err, res) while others have one (res)

Is there a definitive way to know what the callback should look like?

Answer (score 2):

The definitive way to know what a callback should look like is to look at a module's source. You can find that [here](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/index.js) for node-redis, and it is either `(err)` or `(err, res)`. If you only use `(res)` you're just going to get the error instead, if there is one.

Comment: You are right in a general sense and thanks for linking to index.js, but I still don't see where it's defined there... say for example "sismember" ?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/index.js#L691) for the internal callback mechanism for all the commands. The command `sismember` also internally uses that mechanism.

Comment: Yes but that just passes it forward on line 746: command_obj = new Command(command, args, false, buffer_args, callback);

command_obj.callback() itself is called in different ways in a few places (see lines 125 vs. 531 for example) and I see no easy way of knowing the exact parameters any given call should expect to eventually process

Comment: The format is consistent with either `(err)` or `(err, res)`, `res` also being `reply` in some cases. What you see at line 125 is an internal error function. It accepts the error `message` and takes the `command_obj` callback, and callbacks `message` as the error. Therefore, it is still `(err)` in that case.